# django exclude for foreign Key related and count elements

Tags: django, foreign-keys

## is a representation the basic django model relations

### STATIONS_MODEL

state
name
ROUTER ForeignKey(ROUTERS)

### TICKET_MODEL

STATIONS ForeignKey(station, related_name"ticketforstation")
softDelete = bool

### IN VIEW TEMPLATE

context['stations'] = stations_model.objects.all()

### IN TEMPLATE

```
{% for station in stations %}
<div class="container">
 {{station.name}}
 <span>{{station.ticketforstation.all.count}}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I needed count only SOFTDELETE is FALSE

ALSO SIMILAR A

### IN TEMPLATE

```
{% for station in stations %}
<div class="container">
 {{station.name}}
 <span>{{station.ticketforstation.(SOFTDELETED FALSE).count}}</span>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't have idea as with resolved this...

Comment: Please don't use *all caps*, it is seen as screaming. Posts should not try to draw more attention, often that will also work counterproductive anyway.

Comment: For this purpose, you can override the default manager `objects` or create new manager.And exclude soft_deleteed item from the queryset and use that manager in your view for getting the queryset